# Roblox. I don't know and can't think of something to get only X and Z coordinate in lookvector

Tags: roblox, luau

I only need the X and Z coordinates for a look vector in Roblox but i cant think of any way to get only the X and Z coordinates in a look vector.

Answer (score 1):

Since look vector is a vector you should be able to create a new vector using the X and Z components or by multiplying by an XZ vector

```lua
local vector = Vector3.new(.5,.5,.5)
vector = Vector3.new(vector.X, 0, vector.Z)
```

or

```lua
local vector = Vector3.new(.5,.5,.5)
vector = vector * Vector3.new(1,0,1)
```

Comment: Im using the lookvector for getting the horizontal view angle of the player and i dont know how to apply your help to that.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Well the code wont explain too much but basically for the game i need to change the player rotation to the camera rotation but only horizontally.

Comment: If that's your goal, I'd recommend body movers instead as it will be smoother. I created a basic script that accomplishes that you stated above https://pastebin.com/n9FyhsaA

Comment: Well because of bad coding in most of my project its required to use either cframe or vector3